# Translate key-value string with arrays into json object in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, algorithm, dictionary

I have a (flat) text string that I want to translate into a python dictionary / json.

Example string:

```
key1=value key2="val ue" key3=[entry1, entry2] key4=["o ne", "[two]"] key5="value with a , or secial character#l" key6="text with a protected quotation \" inside" key7=1,101,42
```

Output should be a dict/json looking like

```
{
"key1": "value",
"key2": "val ue",
"key3": ["entry1", "entry2"],
"key4": ["o ne", "[two]"],
"key5": "value with a , or secial character#l",
"key6":"text with a protected quotation \" inside",
"key7": [1,101,42]
}
```

I was using lexer as described here https://www.debugcn.com/en/article/15212391.html but I stuck how to use this together with the brackets...

```
    def parse_kv_pairs(text):
        lexer = shlex.shlex(text, posix=True)
        lexer.whitespace = " "
        lexer.wordchars += "="
        lexer.quotes = "\""
        lexer.wordchars += ".-_()/:+*^&%$#@!?|{}[]'`´,"
        return dict(word.split(value_sep, maxsplit=1) for word in lexer)
```

Do you know a library that supports this or do you have an algorithm that is able to translate this?

I'm happy for any hit :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Show what you have tried so far (code) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you cannot get a different input? I can imagine an algorithm for parsing this but it would be tedious to write and there is a lot of edge cases that I think would be difficult to cover. For example, how do you differentiate between [1,2] and "1,2"

Comment: @aneroid I added the code. Main issue to handle are arrays meaning the [] brackets.

Comment: @OndřejBaštař Unfortunately not possible. [1,2] is an array of numbers. Arrays MUST always introduced by brackets, so "1,2" is just a string that contains a comma, see key5 (or key2)

Comment: Okay. Your examples are actually quite extensive. 
I have a feeling that a custom algorithm will have to be created. Either try doing that and we can help you debug or hope that someone will do that for you.
I doesn't sound that bad though.
You could even use eval() to help you, but **only** if you can be sure that the strings are safe.

Comment: key7, is that the integer 110142 ? If so then your example output does not show valid python for key7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could assume that the values (after the equal sign) are JSON compatible, with two exceptions:

- words may appear without quotation marks
- lists may appear without the square brackets (they are recognised by the comma separator)

So, if we can capture the part after the equal sign, we could:

1. identify the quoted strings
2. wrap each unquoted word (that starts with a letter) with double quotes
3. parse that as JSON.
4. If the previous step fails, wrap with square brackets and parse again as JSON

Here is the suggested code:

```
import re 
import json

def parse(s):
    d = {}
    key = value = ""
    for m in re.findall(r'"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|\w+=?|\S', s) + ["="]:
        if m[-1] == '=':  # Arrived at a new key/value pair
            if key:  # Process previous key/value pair
                try:
                    d[key] = json.loads(value)
                except Exception: # Try with brackets, if that fails: input is bad
                    d[key] = json.loads("[{}]".format(value))
            key = m[:-1]  # New key
            value = ""
        elif m[0].isalpha():  # Wrap in quotes
            value += '"{}"'.format(m)
        else:  # Punctuation, digits, ...
            value += m
    return d
```

Here is how you would call that function for the example data you have given:

```
s = r'key1=value key2="val ue" key3=[entry1, entry2] key4=["o ne", "[two]"] key5="value with a , or secial character#l" key6="text with a protected quotation \" inside" key7=1,101,42'

result = parse(s)
```

The result will be:

```
{
   'key1': 'value', 
   'key2': 'val ue', 
   'key3': ['entry1', 'entry2'], 
   'key4': ['o ne', '[two]'], 
   'key5': 'value with a , or secial character#l', 
   'key6': 'text with a protected quotation " inside', 
   'key7': [1, 101, 42]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @trincot. Actually I like the idea most. I did a little regex modification to support also email addresses as value.
Regex:  r'"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|[a-zA-Z0-9@$.!_&#-]+=?|\S

Answer (score 0):

Using regexps I tried to make sense of what you wanted. I stuck to all lowercase as in the example and added a couple of extra gotcha keys of my own for testing.

I assumed that any commas in numbers could be stripped and coded any whitespace characters to be equivalent to a space, allowing the input to be split with extra newlines at spaces instead of the long input, (or not - it can be removed). The code runs and the assertion at the end shows what it produces.

Lists cannot be nested.

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491209/translate-key-value-string-with-arrays-into-json-object-in-python

Created on Fri Mar  5 18:52:01 2021

@author: paddy3118
"""
import re

data = r"""
key1=value key2="val ue" key3=[entry1, entry2] key4=["o ne", "[two]"]
key5="value with a , or secial character#l"
key6="text with a protected quotation \" inside" key7=1,101,42
key8=key9 key10="not a key0=whatewver"
"""
data = data.strip()
space = '\t \n\r'
i = 0
state = 'KEY'
d = {}  # dict for parsed data
while data:
    if state == 'KEY':
        if not (m := re.search(r'^([a-z0-9]+)=', data)):
            break  # d, data
        key = m.groups()[0]
        data = data[m.end():]
        state = 'VAL'
    if state in {'VAL', 'LISTVAL'}:
        if (m:= re.search('^([a-z][a-z0-9]+)[\s,]*', data)):
            val = m.groups()[0]
            if state == 'VAL':
                d[key] = val
                state = 'KEY'
            else:
                listval.append(val)
            data = data[m.end():]
        elif (m:= re.search(r'^"(.*?[^\\])"[\s,]*', data)):
            val = m.groups()[0]
            if state == 'VAL':
                d[key] = val
                state = 'KEY'
            else:
                listval.append(val)
            data = data[m.end():]
        elif (m:= re.search(r'^([0-9][0-9.,]*[^,])[\s,]*', data)):
            val = m.groups()[0]
            val = float(val.replace(',', ''))
            val = int(val) if val.is_integer() else val
            if state == 'VAL':
                d[key] = val
                state = 'KEY'
            else:
                listval.append(val)
            data = data[m.end():]
        elif state == 'VAL' and data[0] == '[':
            listval = []
            state = 'LISTVAL'
            data = data[1:].lstrip()
        elif state == 'LISTVAL' and data[0] == ']':
            d[key] = listval
            state = 'KEY'
            data = data[1:].lstrip()
        else:
            break

assert d == {'key1': 'value',
 'key2': 'val ue',
 'key3': ['entry1', 'entry2'],
 'key4': ['o ne', '[two]'],
 'key5': 'value with a , or secial character#l',
 'key6': 'text with a protected quotation \\" inside',
 'key7': 110142,
 'key8': 'key9',
 'key10': 'not a key0=whatewver'}
```